# What's the best way to prevent losing TextBox focus when there is a validation error?

Tags: wpf, validation, textbox, wpf-controls, focus

I've messed around with `PreviewLostKeyboardFocus` which almost gets you there.  I've seen a couple of implementations using `LostFocus`, but that just forces focus back on the `TextBox` after it's lost focus and you can easily see this shifting on the screen.  Basically, I'm just looking for the same type of behavior you could get with using `OnValidating` in WinForms.

Comment: Catching focus in a control can lead to a poor user experience... Just be sure to let users get out of that dialog/window thing easily...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, the best way is generally not to do it.  It is almost always better to just disable the other controls or prevent saving until the value is valid.

But if your design really needs this ability, here is what you should do:

1. Intercept the `Preview` version of keyboard and mouse events at your window level, or whatever scope you want to prevent focus changes within (eg maybe not your menu bar).
2. When the Tab KeyDown or Return KeyDown is detected in the text box, or when a MouseDown is detected outside the text box while it has the focus, call UpdateSource() on the binding expression, then if the validation has failed set Handled=true to prevent the KeyDown or MouseDown event from being processed further.
3. Also continue handling `PreviewLostKeyboardFocus` to catch any causes of focus change that aren't from the keyboard or mouse, or that your other code didn't recognize.

Comment: how to catch global (window level) mouse events? If we have a container control and focus should stay inside editor until valid data will be passed.

Answer (score 2):

To add onto Ray's answer:

UpdateSource is called like so:

```
BindingExpression be = userTextbox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
be.UpdateSource();
```

Also, as an alternative you can set the text box binding to:

```
UpdateSourceTrigger = "PropertyChanged";
```

The latter will cause a continuous check, whereas the former will check when needed (performant).

Answer (score 1):

If you attempt to focus an element inside its own LostFocus handler you will face a StackOverflowException, I'm not sure about the root cause (I suspect the focus kind of bounces around) but there is an easy workaround: dispatch it.

```
private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var element = (sender as TextBox);
    if (!theTextBoxWasValidated())
    {
        // doing this would cause a StackOverflowException
        // element.Focus();
        var restoreFocus = (System.Threading.ThreadStart)delegate { element.Focus(); };
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(restoreFocus);
    }
}
```

Through Dispatcher.BeginInvoke you make sure that restoring the focus doesn't get in the way of the in-progress loss of focus (and avoid the nasty exception you'd face otherwise)