# Best way to keep focus on DatePicker when validation error

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, datagridtemplatecolumn

I found this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163303/whats-the-best-way-to-prevent-losing-textbox-focus-when-there-is-a-validation-e), and it seems to work (mostly) for the TextBox in a DataGridTextColumn.

How would I implement the similar behavior for a DataGridTemplateColumn that has a DatePicker in the CellEditingTemplate?
This code seems to get called endlessly, suggesting that we are trying to set the focus to the wrong element:

```
private void DatePickerLostFocusHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {  
     // What is the correct property to use here?
     // datePicker.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();

        if (Validation.GetHasError(datePicker))
        {
            // Looks like this is setting focus to wrong element -- it ends up getting called repeatedly.

            var element = (sender as DatePicker);
            var restoreFocus = (System.Threading.ThreadStart)delegate { element.Focus(); };
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(restoreFocus);
        }
    }
```

Thanks for any insights ---